# Difficulty with creation of filenames based on string using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I am creating a vector of filenames based on a string sequence. The string "ABcd" should produce a vector of filenames "mypath/A.txt", "mypath/B.txt", "mypath.cc.txt" and "mypath/dd.txt".

I am trying this with a for loop but the resulting vector only contains the last filename. Also my code is long and inefficient. i would like to know 1) why it does not work and 2) any suggestions for better coding.

```
mystring <- "ABcd"

# count number of characters
stringlength <- nchar(mystring)

# define file path 
filepath <- "mypath"

# initialize vectors
filename <- rep("NA", stringlength)
files <- rep("NA", stringlength)
symbol <- rep("NA", stringlength)
prefix <- "NA"

# create filename prefix from letters in mystring - caps are single and lowercase are double
for (i in stringlength) 
{
  symbol[i] <- substring(mystring, i, i)
  if (symbol[i] %in% letters) {
    prefix <- paste(symbol[i], symbol[i], sep = "")
  } else {
    prefix <- symbol[i]
  }
  filename[i] <- paste(filepath, "/", prefix, ".txt", sep="")
  files <- c(files, filename[i])
}
```

Comment: In your `for` loop, you probably want `(i in seq_len(stringlength))`. The way you've written it is `for (i in 4)` instead of `for (i in c(1, 2, 3, 4))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had two errors. First, as pointed out, my for loop was wrong and does not loop over the number of characters as desired. Replacing "for (i in string length)" with "for (i in seq_len(string length))" corrected this.

Second, the line "files <- c(files, filename[i])" causes the loop to add new entries to the pre-existing NAs, instead of just giving the desired vector of filenames. Replacing with appropriate indexing using "files[i] <- filename[i]" fixes this.

```
mystring <- "ABcd"

# count number of characters
stringlength <- nchar(mystring)

# find filename for image corresponding to symbol
filepath <- "/Users/mypath"

# initialize vectors
filename <- rep("NA", stringlength)
files <- rep("NA", stringlength)
symbol <- rep("NA", stringlength)
prefix <- "NA"

# create filename prefix from letters in mystring - caps are single and lowercase are double
for (i in seq_len(stringlength)) 
{
  symbol[i] <- substring(mystring, i, i)
  if (symbol[i] %in% letters) {
    prefix <- paste(symbol[i], symbol[i], sep = "")
  } else {
    prefix <- symbol[i]
  }
  filename[i] <- paste(filepath, "/", prefix, ".txt", sep="")
files[i] <- filename[i]
}
files
1] "/Users/mypath/A.txt"  "/Users/mypath/B.txt"  "/Users/mypath/cc.txt" "/Users/mypath/dd.txt"
```